# How to cherry-pick only certain file type from a commit

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to just select certain file types from a commit. Example
If we have 10 files (5->.java+ 5->.png). I want to select only .png files changes/files from the commit. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Cherry picking selects certain _commits_, not files, to come into a certain branch.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I want to select certain file types only from a particular commit. How can I achieve this, other than selecting one by one each file. Any way to achieve this.

Comment: I have given you one option below as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git `cherry-pick` applies an entire *commit* from some other branch or location to your current branch.  If instead you want to reset a handful of *files* to some other commit, then use this form of `git checkout`:

```
git checkout abcd1234 -- path/to/file1.java path/to/file2.png   # etc.
```

where `abcd1234` is the SHA-1 hash of the commit from which you want to take the Java and PNG files.  This will update these selected files in your working directory, but won't stage or commit them.

**Edit:**

To checkout all `PNG` files at a certain path, change directories to the folder where all the files are located, and then use:

```
git checkout abcd1234 -- "*.png"
```

Comment: But for this I have to put each file name here. Is there's a way to select in bulk (*.png)

Answer (score 1):

From Git base command:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commitedHashCode>
```

Example:

```
git cherry-pick -n 54f1a843aece872dda792bd8c036994bbee08434
```

Note: -n is indicating cherry-pic code will not commit in your local branch. It will bring all the changes into your local branch without commit.

Now you have the option to delete all .java file(or whatever you want to keep) from your local branch then do the commit and push action.